# iPhone 13( iOS 15.0 ) Error loading page, Domain NSURLErrorDomain, Error Code 1001, Description: The request timed out

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios15

When tried to access a URL link in iPhone 13( iOS 15.0 ) browser, getting “Error loading page, Domain NSURLErrorDomain, Error Code 1001, Description: The request timed out”. We are loading the same URL in webview in our iOS app. It is not working in the app also. Giving the same error

Using high speed Wifi and Cellular data. No connectivity issues. Verified speed of connectivity in this phone. Not getting this issue in any other iPhones/ iPads. There the URL is loading fine within seconds

Same URL is accessible in Laptop and desktop computers in same network connectivity

Will there be any settings to edit or device specific issues that cause this?

Comment: Have you tried resetting network settings? You can do this in Settings -> Transfer or Reset -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings